# "boost" a document based on tags from a text classification model (Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing a corpus of documents (news articles,forum posts etc.) into an Elasticsearch. To provide better search, I have also trained a SVM+Tf-Idf model classifying document to generate tags into a taxonomy e.g. `News- Politics`, `News-Sports`,`Post-US Politics` etc.  My question: how do I weight the scores generated by the classifier to writing the document into ES?

I have been using a hackish approach, for example if I get the `score` of 0.7 for `News-Sports`, I write the ["News-Sports"] * int(score*10) i.e. write `News-Sports` as 7 terms into the `tags` field of  the document.

Are there better ways of doing index-time weighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I entirely understand your question. I understand it as how do you add a weight for each generated tag that could impact relevancy.

If that's the case, you could make use of `field_value_factor`. You could write both tag and it's weight into a document and then use a function query to boost by these values.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/boosting-by-popularity.html

Comment: yep, exactly what i needed. Thanks so much!